# firebase SSR problem, "App requesting permission to access your google account" pops up instead of website

Tags: reactjs, firebase, server-side-rendering

I have attempted to make a react SSR website using create-React basics through the "razzle" helper tool.

the app originally worked with this:

```
'use strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = require('./server/build/server.bundle.js').default;

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

but when I changed it to this:

```
'use strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const App = require('./server/build/server.bundle.js').default;


const React = require('react')
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs'); 
const app = express();
const {RenderToString} = require('react-dom/server');


const index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname +'/index.html', 'utf8');

app.get ('**', (req, res) => {
    const html = RenderToString(App);
    const finalHtml = index.replace('<!-- ::APP:: -->', html)
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, sMax-age=1200');
    res.send(finalHtml);
}) 


exports.shell = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

instead of the website i got

An application is requesting permission to access your Google Account.
Please select an account that you would like to use.

and upon attempting entry with the firebase admin gmail account:

Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /app/ from this server.

What have I done wrong, and how do I fix this?

The original function which worked for SSR was removed, and the new one exports.shell was added sucessfully.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? I'm also facing this issue.

Comment: seems to happen when the function does not actually work but he console does not tell you why.
my problem (with the ssr firebase) was following depricated mostly youtube information when i should have just used razzle.

Comment: and using razzle I altered the wrong file. The answer provided was what solved it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the function has problems within it that are not adressed through processes such as eslint, then it will cause the permission webpage instead of your natural webpage.

The problem here is that using the Razzle package you have the "renderTOSTring" placed in another file.

If the thing worked with no "renderTOString" there using react it will not when it is placed in there.

To adjust the razzle config so that you can both add in "firebase caching" and adjust the routing. ou need to go to the "src/server.js file generated by razzle.

TO add caching and routing it should look like this:

```
import App from './App';
import React from 'react';
import express from 'express';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const assets = require(process.env.RAZZLE_ASSETS_MANIFEST);

const server = express();

server
  .disable('x-powered-by')
  .use(express.static(process.env.RAZZLE_PUBLIC_DIR))
  .get('/*', (req, res) => {
    const markup = renderToString(    <StaticRouter
      location={req.url}
      context={context}
    >
      <App /></StaticRouter>);
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=1600');
    res.send(
      `<!doctype html>
    <html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charSet='utf-8' />
        <title>Welcome to Razzle</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        ${assets.client.css
          ? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${assets.client.css}">`
          : ''}
         ${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
           ? `<script src="${assets.client.js}" defer></script>`
           : `<script src="${assets.client.js}" defer crossorigin></script>`}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root">${markup}</div>
    </body>
</html>`
    );
  });

export default server;
```

with the changes being here :

```
 <StaticRouter
  location={req.url}
  context={context}
>
  <App /></StaticRouter>);
res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=1600');
```

Comment: I was using Next.js instead of Razzle but some of what you have discovered here may still be applicable. That part of my project has got pushed aside for now but when I get back to it I'll update you with whatever I find as the issue.

Comment: sweet, nextjs I think cant use the caching mechanism than normal ssr react can because of how it updates if that's of any value.

Answer (score 1):

You can be forwarded to the same page with message "App requesting permission to access your google account" when your Firebase Function is deployed to another region than "us-central1", because:

> Important: Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1
> only.