# Firebase Cloud Function is not accessible to the public [An application is requesting permission to access your Google Account.]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've just used Express with Firebase Cloud Functions and made an endpoint.

```
app.get('/time', (req, res) => {
    const date = new Date();
    const hours = (date.getHours() % 12) + 1;  // London is UTC + 1hr;
    res.json({bongs: 'BONG '.repeat(hours)});
});
```

The endpoint is accessible publicly with the path:

```
https://<region>-<project-name>.cloudfunctions.net/app/time
```

where app is from entry source index.js:

```
exports.app = functions.region('asia-east2').https.onRequest(app);
```

However, it's not accessible with the path:

```
https://<project-name>.web.app/app/time
```

It requires me to grant the permission and select my Google account by default. How come? The endpoint is for public access.

Did I miss anything to setup and how to solve this problem?

[image]

If I don't use Express Framework, both the above 2 paths are accessible for public. (i.e. Call functions from your app, https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

Thank you~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unaccessible path implies that you're trying to access Cloud Functions with Firebase Hosting. That error appears when there is a problem accessing your Function. Just to give you an idea, here's a thread with similar error:

[firebase SSR problem, "App requesting permission to access your google account" pops up instead of website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64486898/firebase-ssr-problem-app-requesting-permission-to-access-your-google-account)

> **Imporant Note**: Before going to the solution, you must know that Firebase Hosting currently supports Cloud Functions that are in **[us-central1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client-callable_functions)**. You can't use any other regions for your function such as asia-east2.

Moving forward, you need to setup rewrite rules in the hosting section to serve the subpath you configured on your Express App:

**firebase.json**:

```
"hosting": {
  "public": "public",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],  
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/time",
    "function": "app"
  } ]
}
```

If you do this correctly, you should be able to access your function through this path:

```
https://<project-name>.web.app/time
```

> Note that the path in Firebase Hosting is **/time**, not **/app/time**.

---

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#use_a_web_framework

Comment: Oh... that's why I can't access via the hosting because mine was asia-east2...

I hope Firebase can support more regions soon.