# How to Fix Permission Issues in Firebase Cloud Functions (Nextjs Experimental Hosting)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have an issue related to Firestore, Hosting, and Cloud functions. I deployed a Nextjs application using the just-released experimental web framework support. I'm using Nextjs's Image API, and as expected, the Firebase CLI creates a cloud function for the project. Everything works fine at the start, but when I try to open a page in the application that reads some data from Firestore, it redirects to an auth page, which is unexpected.

[image: Page redirected to upon error]

Even when I auth with my Google account (since that's the logged-in user to the application), it returns a forbidden error and logs me out.

[image: Error message]

When I go back and try again, it returns a different error (most likely because I was logged out automatically).

[image: Error message]

I tried doing some research, and some people suggested adding an `allUsers` principal permission to Cloud functions, but that didn't work (`Error: Principals of type allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers cannot be added to this resource`), and that's even insecure permission. Only authenticated users should be able to read data from the page as already configured in my Firestore security rules. So it's unclear what I need to do since Firebase created the Cloud function automatically or if this is related to my security rules and cloud functions.

What could be wrong? Everything works fine in my existing deployment setup to Netlify (where Edge functions are created automatically using their Nextjs plugin). I'm only trying to test the new Firebase web framework hosting features. Please let me know if you'd need me to provide some more context or debug files to better help you help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The message “ App requesting permission to access your google account “ pops up if the function runs in any region other than `us-central1`.

Currently, Firebase Hosting does not support Cloud Functions in any other regions, Except [`us-central1`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client-callable_functions).

You can refer to this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66523768/18265570).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! That error no longer pops up now (I redeployed the project), but instead, I get a 500 server error when I try to access the page that reads some data from Firestore using a client-side rendering approach. By default, Firebase creates a cloud function with `us-central1` region) so it's unclear what to do on my end.